# where does scm plugin store the crendentials

Tags: maven-2, maven-scm-plugin

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <groupId>a</groupId>
  <artifactId>a</artifactId>
  <name>SCM Sample Project</name>
  <url>http://somecompany.com</url>

   <scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://my-svn-url/trunk/</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://my-svn-url/trunk/</developerConnection>
    <url>scm:svn:http://my-svn-url/trunk/</url>
  </scm>
  <build>
  </build>

</project>
```

As you can see I have no svn crendentials I am still able to checkout project.
More of I think maven stores all these credentials somewhere in cache as it is NOT taking my basic configurations as "checkoutDirectory". Can anybody please help on how to clean cache ...or I am missin something :(

Answer (score 0):

The [settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers) file is the correct location for username/passwords:

```xml
<server>
  <id>my-svn-url</id>
  <username>TheUserIAmOnSVN</username>
  <password>MySVNPassword</password>
</server>
```

Special things for Subversion you can [configure into the scm provider](http://maven.apache.org/scm/subversion.html).

If you are working locally Subversion stores username/passwords in it's own cache ($HOME/.svn/)...